# Advanced C++ multiple parentheses

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm reviewing a sample program code and found this line:

```
auto prerequisite = task<void>([](){});
```

What is the meaning of those combined parentheses `([](){})`

I'm a cpp programmer but do not know advance cpp (c11+) which this Microsoft example is written at. Googling didn't help, and I don't know the name of those operators.

Comment: Have a look for C++ lambdas

Comment: related/dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11 . These are completely different questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[](){}` is a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that creates a function object that has non-zero size and does nothing.

This is probably to avoid checking whether `prerequisite` is valid/exists - it is always valid, but may do nothing.